# Trying to cross compile Boost 1.46.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 to Arm Linux

Tags: boost, compilation

I've got a cross compile tool chain for the arm, and am successfully compiling a fairly large application with it on Ubuntu 10.10.

Now I'm trying to introduce boost 1.46.1.  I have done what the boost cross compile directions say.  Namely running bootstrap.sh, modifying user-config.jam to add the line:

```
using gcc : arm : /path/to/compiler/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ ;
```

When I issue:

```
 ./bjam --toolchain=gcc-arm
```

bjam compiles boost, but when I do a:

```
 file ..../something.o
```

The output indicates an Intel 80386 ELF file, not an arm file.  I've sanity checked with other application arm objects and the file command reports arm not 80386.

I have tried setting my `PATH` to put the cross compile binaries first and setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the arm compiler libraries, but nothing I've done seems to be able to keep bjam from compiling for Intel.

Answer (score 5):

Features do not begin with `--`, and `toolchain` is not a valid feature; make that:

`bjam toolset=gcc-arm`

Answer (score 1):

A very convenient way to debug issues with bjam is to include the `-n` argument. It will print all the command lines, instead of executing them. Then you'll see which g++ is actually being invoked.

If you already built everything, you might want to include `-a` as well, which means "rebuild everything from scratch"